# trouble formatting year correctly in C#

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I have a function where I am pulling values from multiple sources and placing them in a txt file. I need for it to format the year to yy. I have tried multiple ideas and still can't seem to figure it out. Below Is what I am currently doing. It places the hour minute day and month in like I want for it to. For some reason I can't seem to get the year to format correctly. It currently comes out as 2013, not 13.

```
DateTime dt = System.DateTime.Now;
string format = dt.Year.ToString("yy");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dt.Year` is an integer value. To use a `DateTime` format string, you should just use:

```
dt.ToString("yy")
```

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that you are using the format string on the Year directly, alas, Year is an int - an int won't know anything about Date formatting. Instead, try

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yy")
```

With DateTime.now just being an example DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can try this

```
 DateTime dt = System.DateTime.Now;
 string format = dt.ToString("yy");
```

So Here you can pass any of the `format` you want from `DateTime` value.